# How to change the color of scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Dataset is below

```
sino,cost,profit,product
1,567510,359807,600
2,256203,154802,459
3,523447,664310,655
4,201928,449702,778
5,270359,913417,659
```

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df1 = df[['cost','profit','product']]
sns.pairplot(df1)
```

- My graph is below.
- What is the analysis from the Plot
- How to change the color for first cost is red, profit for blue,product is green

[image]

Comment: So do you want to plot the diagonal in different color?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, i need to plot like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sns.pairplot()` returns a grid of axes. You can then access the diagonal figures using `axes.diag_axes` and then access the patches (bars) for which you can change the color as desired.

The following code does the work.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

df1 = df[['cost','profit','product']]
axes = sns.pairplot(df1)
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g']

for col, ax in zip(colors, axes.diag_axes):
    barlist=filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, mpl.patches.Rectangle), ax.get_children())
    for bar in barlist:
        bar.set_color(col)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the analysis from the Plot ? Thanks Sheldore

Comment: @Nons To intrepret the plot, you need to read the documentation of `pairplot`. This question doesn't typically fall within the scope of Stack Overflow